# Jquery Datatable referenced only through CDN works not with script files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I want to call my datatable by referencing relevant jquery files in MVC. But when I try to call dataTable instance it fails.

The error in chrome shows 'dataTable()' function not recognized or sometimes the jquery or $ is not recognized.

Following is my code with CDN which works:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>`<div style="width: 900px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px">
    <table id="datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Job Title</th>
                <th>Web Site</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Hire Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var values in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@values.Id</td>
                    <td>@values.FirstName</td>
                    <td>@values.LastName</td>
                    <td>@values.Gender</td>
                    <td>@values.JobTitle</td>
                    <td>@values.WebSite</td>
                    <td>@values.Salary</td>
                    <td>@values.HireDate</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Job Title</th>
                <th>Web Site</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Hire Date</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

$('#datatable').dataTable();

Now if I call the same code referencing dataTable script files downloaded via 'Add -> Client Side Library' from visual studio and downloading datatable cdnjs files, it fails.

Following code fails:

```
<link href="~/lib/datatable/css/datatable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`<script src="~/lib/datatable/js/datatable.jquery.min.js"></script>`<script src="~/lib/datatable/js/datatable.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 900px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px">
<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Job Title</th>
            <th>Web Site</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Hire Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var values in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@values.Id</td>
                <td>@values.FirstName</td>
                <td>@values.LastName</td>
                <td>@values.Gender</td>
                <td>@values.JobTitle</td>
                <td>@values.WebSite</td>
                <td>@values.Salary</td>
                <td>@values.HireDate</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Job Title</th>
            <th>Web Site</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Hire Date</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

```
<script>
 $('#datatable').dataTable();
</script>
```

Any help or suggestions or ideas, on how to reference jquery files for datatable in MVC 5 project?.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems ok. you just need to add call datatable method in document ready function

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#datatable").dataTable();
})
</script>
```

After adding Ready function. check you are not loading JQuery twice.(ie. check in _Layout.cshtml page.)if so remove jquery reference from view.

Also make sure you are referencing valid datatable.js path.

Comment: verify that jquery and datatable script loaded correctly

Answer (score 0):

You should change jQuery version to `jQuery 1.11.3`

https://datatables.net/blog/2015-04-30

Comment: The post is from 2015. I am using 3.3.1, so will that not work?.

Comment: Datatabes 1.10.7 base on jQuery 1.x you need use jQuery 1.x version

Comment: That was the CDN version, but the datatable jquery i downloaded from VS using Client Side library, would be the latest.